# Postgres FDW join query on local and foreign table is slow with ORDER BY and JSONB data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, postgres-fdw

I have two tables the local table `debtors` and the foreign table `debtor_registry`. I'm using PostgreSQL v13.

My problem here is whenever I try the following query, It takes **14secs** to get the 1000 records.

```
SELECT 
    debtors.id,
    debtors.name,
    debtor_registry.settings
FROM debtors
    INNER JOIN debtor_registry ON debtor_registry.id = debtors.registry_uuid
ORDER BY name LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

I was surprised that whenever I removed the `ORDER BY` clause from the query, It become faster only took **194ms** for 1000 records.

```
SELECT 
    debtors.id,
    debtors.name,
    debtor_registry.settings
FROM debtors
    INNER JOIN debtor_registry ON debtor_registry.id = debtors.registry_uuid
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

Also, another case is if I remove the `settings` which is a JSONB field from the query, and retain the `ORDER BY` clause. It only took **101ms** to get 1000 records.

```
SELECT 
    debtors.id,
    debtors.name
FROM debtors
    INNER JOIN debtor_registry ON debtor_registry.id = debtors.registry_uuid
ORDER BY name LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

I'm suspecting that It might be related to how much data I am trying to get.

Here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` result if the `settings` JSONB fields, `ORDER BY name` and `LIMIT 1000` are in the query:

```
Limit  (cost=114722.78..114725.28 rows=1000 width=57) (actual time=13712.125..14002.827 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Output: debtors.id, debtors.name, debtor_registry.settings
  ->  Sort  (cost=114722.78..114725.63 rows=1140 width=57) (actual time=13703.171..13993.617 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Output: debtors.id, debtors.name, debtor_registry.settings
        Sort Key: debtors.name
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 82752kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=896.60..114664.90 rows=1140 width=57) (actual time=14.889..917.360 rows=10550 loops=1)
              Output: debtors.id, debtors.name, debtor_registry.settings
              Hash Cond: (((debtor_registry.id)::character varying)::text = (debtors.registry_uuid)::text)
              ->  Foreign Scan on public.debtor_registry  (cost=100.00..113832.74 rows=1137 width=48) (actual time=8.845..902.466 rows=10529 loops=1)
                    Output: debtor_registry.id, debtor_registry.company_id, debtor_registry.settings, debtor_registry.product
                    Remote SQL: SELECT id, settings FROM public.company_debtor
              ->  Hash  (cost=664.60..664.60 rows=10560 width=62) (actual time=6.027..6.028 rows=10554 loops=1)
                    Output: debtors.id, debtors.name, debtors.registry_uuid
                    Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1108kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.debtors  (cost=0.00..664.60 rows=10560 width=62) (actual time=0.019..4.726 rows=10560 loops=1)
                          Output: debtors.id, debtors.name, debtors.registry_uuid
Planning Time: 0.098 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 10
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.609 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.674 ms, Emission 7.991 ms, Total 10.274 ms
Execution Time: 14007.113 ms
```

How can I make the 1st query faster without omitting the `settings` field and the `ORDER BY name` clause and `LIMIT 1000`?

> UPDATE

1. I also found this similar [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/179744/135744) but the answer does not solve my problem. Since our sorting is dynamic and we build queries based on the frontend client request.
2. Setting `use_remote_estimate` to 'true' doesn't help either. :(

Comment: Strange that the sort takes that long. Does it improve when you increase `work_mem`?

Comment: The sorting seems to be triggered after the `join` and takes a lot of memory due to the data of the column `debtor_registry.settings` possibly. I'm not an expert but I would suggest you to trigger the sorting on the column `debtors.name` before the `join` with the `debtor_registry` table, by using a cte for instance.

Comment: With PostgreSQL v13, toasted values should not be de-toasted until later...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah by default it is `4MB` now I set it to `1GB` and now it works. However I'm not sure if this is possible in a managed db in DigitalOcean.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  "With PostgreSQL v13, toasted values should not be de-toasted until later" What does it means?

Comment: That it shouldn't matter if there is a large column value, because it is only retrieved for the 1000 result rows.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you mean that Edouard's suggestion won't work?

Comment: @EdouardH. looks like it worked when you try to sort the `debtors` table first then join it to the foreign table.

Comment: Sorry @EdouardH. but the sorting result is not persistent.

Comment: @Roel, my idea corresponds to the second suggestion of Stefanov.sm, with a second order by after the inner join so that to keep the right order if it is not persistent.

Comment: @EdouardH. I guess you are right, Stefanov.sm 2nd suggestion saved my ass here :D

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I suspect the large column was already detoasted by the FDW before it ever got to the sort.

Comment: Does every debtor have exactly one entry in the registry?

Comment: @jjanes hi and yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
with t as materialized
(
 SELECT -- your second query as-is
    debtors.id,
    debtors.name,
    debtor_registry.settings
 FROM debtors
    INNER JOIN debtor_registry ON debtor_registry.id = debtors.registry_uuid
 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
)
select * from t ORDER BY name;
```

i.e. keep the plan of the quick second query and order the resultset after that.
If your Postgresql version is before 12 then omit `materialized` as CTEs are always materialized.

Second suggestion - sort/limit locally, pick the right records upfront and then pull fat `debtor_registry.settings` for only 1000 records.

```sql
with t as materialized
(
 SELECT d.id, d.name, d.registry_uuid 
 FROM debtors d
 ORDER BY d.name
 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
)
select t.id, t.name, debtor_registry.settings
FROM t INNER JOIN debtor_registry ON debtor_registry.id = t.registry_uuid
ORDER BY t.name;
```

Comment: Weird it works! Took only 1 sec. I hope I could improve it to less than a second :D

Comment: That's a different query; it does not select the first 1000 rows in the desired ordering.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ahhh yeah you are right, It only pull the first 1000 records and then order them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Fair enough, it is not.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm still thanks for answering man

Comment: I will try the new suggestion. I didn't notice the update.

Comment: Now it gave me the right result this time. Thank you man!